# Setting conditions in C# for Database making sure dates in columns should not be equal to a selection in html form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I have an `Asp.Net` MVC project where I have connected my database to my project and everything is working fine where all the data is being sorted into MicrosofSQL ql server by an ID included.

Now the problem I am running into is i have two date columns in my Database table named "pickupDate" & "dropoffDate" the data being stored my the columns are the selections someone makes in a date text box. Now lets say someone Selects a date from pickupDate that has already been picked and stored into the database.

How can i set a condition to not equal any date that is stored into bot columns of the database?

I will put my Controller in a reference to see the data being stored into the database.

```
CarRentalSQLEntities5 db = new CarRentalSQLEntities5();
                    RentalSchedule rentaltbl = new RentalSchedule();
                    rentaltbl.Car = model.Car;
                    rentaltbl.pickupDate = model.pickupDate.ToString();
                    rentaltbl.dropoffDate = model.dropoffDate.ToString();
                    rentaltbl.PhoneNum = model.PhoneNum;
                    rentaltbl.Email = model.Email;

                    db.RentalSchedules.Add(rentaltbl);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    int lastestid = rentaltbl.ID;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                return RedirectToAction("HomePage");

            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Put a UNIQUE index in the database. Try and save it. If it fails with a unique index violation, notify the user and let them try again. You could _theoretically_ read all of the existing dates out of the database but that isn't bulletproof (since a new date could be inserted between your read and write).

Answer (score 0):

Set the pickupDate column as unique in the database table definition. Then put your segment of code to store data inside a try{} block and then catch the constraint violation exception inside the catch{} block as below:

```
  catch(SqlException ex)
    {
       if(ex.Number == 2627) // Unique constraint error
       {
          // throw a user readable exception message
       }
    }
```

you can check other SqlException code in the sql site. I have shown an example which works under sqlserver and EF6.

Comment: Can I do something like this where i can say if(x.pickupDate == x.selectionDate){ return "this Date already exist"}

Comment: yes you can do, but in that case you have to search and fetch data from the table/storage and then check against the current selection. But If you set the table column to unique then the particular column will not allow you to store the same data again, and if you go to store the same data then the above exception will be thrown which you need to catch.So, no need to check manually, and it is efficient as well.